# Java: cannot update Excel using JDBC ODBC

Tags: java, excel, jdbc, odbc

I can read rows/columns just fine, but I can't update, insert or delete.

```
try{
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
            String myDB = "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls)};DBQ=myExcelFile.xls;"
+
                          "DriverID=22;READONLY=false";
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(myDB, username, password);
            stmt = con.createStatement();
            stmt = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
            rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM [users$]");
            while (rs.next()) {
                String str = rs.getString("username");
                System.out.println(str);
                rs.updateString("username", str + "UPDATED");
                rs.updateRow();
            }
            rs.close();
            stmt.close();
            con.close();
        }catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);}
```

This code fails when it reached `rs.updateRow();` and displays this error:

> java.sql.SQLException:
>   [Microsoft][ODBC Excel Driver]Error in
>   row

Note: Some people say it's because of READONLY is not set to false or 0, but I've done it already, and the Excel file is also not set to read-only

I followed the steps to apply **Updating Rows in ResultSet Objects** in here: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/retrieving.html

Comment: to limit the possibilities of errors, why not change your select statement to SELECT username FROM [users$]? There is always the possibility that there really is an "error in row".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May you should to consider the [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) for excel integration.

Comment: Thanks. Now I'm using apache POI, but I'm having the same problem, I can't update rows! In this link http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#ReadWriteWorkbook it's said that I should use Workbook and other instances that are NOT part of HSSF package, while in this tutorial (http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2003/04/16/poi_excel.html) teaches me to use POI with HSSF package! What's the difference!! I'm so confused now! Plz help

Comment: Sorry, I didn't answer before because I'm not POI specialist. Maybe someone in the mail listing should help. Or just create another question in StackOverFlow using POI terms.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to use Apache POI http://poi.apache.org/  and some codes here: http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2003/04/16/poi_excel.html

Here is the code:

```
FileInputStream myInput = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(myInput);

XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(0); 
XSSFCell cell = row.getCell(1);
cell.setCellValue(123);


sheet.getRow(37).getCell(13). setCellValue("USD");
```

It succesfully update the cell or you can change this code to your situation (update row).

HSSF is for *Excel '97(-2007)* file format and XSSF is for *Excel 2007 OOXML (.xlsx)* . (poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/index.html) I think there shouln't be any problem while updating

If you have any question please write to me

Comment: Thanks. Now I'm using apache POI, but I'm having the same problem, I can't update rows! In this link http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#ReadWriteWorkbook it's said that I should use Workbook and other instances that are NOT part of HSSF package, while the 2nd link (http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2003/04/16/poi_excel.html) teaches me to use POI with HSSF package! What's the difference!! I'm so confused now! Plz help

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to Update, Insert and Delete. Use,
`stmt.executeUpdate("query")` instead of `stmt.executeQuery("query")`.

Answer (score 0):

A resultSet is not the typical means for updating through JDBC. (Normally insert, update statements are used.)

There is a paragraph in the tutorial link that you posted that explains the default result set is read only.  It says:

**The default ResultSet concurrency is CONCUR_READ_ONLY.
    Note: Not all JDBD drivers and databases support concurrency. The method DatabaseMetaData.supportsResultSetConcurrency returns true if the specified concurrency level is supported by the driver and false otherwise.**

Answer (score 0):

I am able update excel file using JDBC, you can use below code, this code updates a file in D:/Test.xls and Updates Col1 with 'Test' where Col2 is 'Testing' :

```
    java.sql.Statement stmt=null;
    PreparedStatement ps=null;
    Connection con=null;

    con = java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection( "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls)};DBQ=D:/Test.xls;ReadOnly=False;");

    ps=con.prepareStatement("Update [Sheet1$] Set Col1='Test' Where Col2='Testing');
    ps.executeUpdate();
```